# How can I update a @Published value from a Timer block without warnings

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-concurrency

I have the following code:

```
class Recorder: ObservableObject {
    @Published var recordingTimeSeconds: TimeInterval = 0
    private var timer: Timer?
    
    init() {}
    
    func startRecording() {
        timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { t in  
            self.recordingTimeSeconds = t.timeInterval
        })
        
        RunLoop.main.add(timer!, forMode: .common)
    }
}
```

I have the `-warn-concurrency` compiler flag enabled in my project. The line `self.recordingTimeSeconds` gives me the following warning: `Capture of 'self' with non-sendable type 'Recorder' in a '@Sendable' closure`

<strike>One solution that does not give warnings is:</strike>

**EDIT:** The solutions below do give the same warning. XCode just didn't want to show them to me at the time of writing this question

```
Task { @MainActor [timeInterval = t.timeInterval] in
    self.recordingTimeSeconds = timeInterval
}
```

Alternatively

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [seconds = t.timeInterval] in
    self.recordingTimeSeconds = seconds
}
```

But I would like to see an alternative solution since I feel like using a `DispatchQueue` or `Task` might introduce issues later. The timer in my case needs to update the value without any possible delays.

Comment: There are probably other more reliable ways of detecting recoded time. Such as recording the actual start time and then displaying a timer with Text and style or TimelineView, etc. timers aren’t reliable, they are not precise and get stopped for different reasons.

Comment: `self.recordingTimeSeconds = t.timeInterval` would always set `recordingTimeSeconds` to 1. Did you mean `self.recordingTimeSeconds += 1` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of the general question of how to access properties from the timer closure:

1. You can use `Task { @MainActor in … }` pattern:

   ```swift
   @MainActor                                                  // Apple recommends if you're publishing for UI, isolate the whole ObservableObject to the main actor
   class Recorder: ObservableObject {
       @Published var recordingTimeSeconds: TimeInterval = 0
       private weak var timer: Timer?                          // weak

       func startRecording() {
           timer = .scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in
               Task { @MainActor [interval = timer.timeInterval] in
                   self.recordingTimeSeconds = interval
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   The overhead seems to be minimal, but benchmark with and without the `Task { @MainActor in … }` and draw your own conclusions.

   A few unrelated observations:

   - Apple advises isolating `ObservableObject` to the main actor. See WWDC 2021’s [Discover concurrency in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10019/?time=1290).

     The key observation is that both the `Task {…}` and the property have to be isolated to the same actor. In your example, the property is not actor-isolated at all, hence the warning. Isolating the entire `ObservableObject` to the main actor, as Apple recommends, is the easiest way to accomplish this.
   - If you do that, you can just schedule a timer and it will be added to the main run loop for you, simplifying the code.
   - I personally always use `weak` reference to the timer. The runloop keeps the strong reference for us. As soon as the timer is invalidated, we want our `timer` reference to become `nil`.
   - Note, I am capturing the `timeInterval` explicitly, which avoids warnings about whether `Timer` is `Sendable` or not. (For more information on `Sendable` types, see WWDC 2022 video [Eliminate data races using Swift Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110351).)
2. Personally, I now avoid using `Timer`, and remain within the Swift concurrency system. Sometimes a simple loop with [`Task.sleep`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/sleep(for:tolerance:clock:)) is sufficient. E.g.:

   ```swift
   @MainActor
   class Recorder: ObservableObject {
       @Published var recordingTimeSeconds: TimeInterval = 0

       func startRecording() async throws {
           while true {
               try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
               …
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   This probably is not relevant in this particular “recording” example, but often when you want to run something roughly every second, the above is sufficient.

   Regardless, by remaining in Swift concurrency, if this asynchronous task is canceled, `Task.sleep` will throw `CancellationError` and you will exit this loop. And unlike legacy `sleep` API, which are best avoided, the `Task.sleep` is non-blocking.

   Anyway, given that `startRecording` is `async` and is isolated to the main actor, this simultaneously will avoid blocking the actor/thread, but give you timer-related behaviors.

   Clearly, you will need to calculate the interval yourself, though.
3. Perhaps more elegant than the above, is to use [`AsyncTimerSequence`](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Timer.md) from Apple’s [Swift Async Algorithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/) package:

   ```swift
   @MainActor
   class Recorder: ObservableObject {
       @Published var recordingTimeSeconds: TimeInterval = 0

       func startRecording() async throws {
           for await tick in AsyncTimerSequence(interval: .seconds(1), clock: .continuous) {
               …
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Again, you may need to calculate the interval yourself (e.g., with [`ContinuousClock`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/continuousclock)).

   And if you want to minimize the latitude you offer the OS regarding when this fires, you can specify a `tolerance` of `.zero`:

   ```swift
   for await tick in AsyncTimerSequence(interval: .seconds(1), tolerance: .zero, clock: .continuous) {
       …
   }
   ```
4. FWIW, with these Swift concurrency patterns, you have to contemplate how to cancel a previously started timer. If you are starting this in a [`.task`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(priority:_:)) view modifier and want it stopped when you leave, it will cancel for you automatically.

   But if you are starting this manually (e.g., when the “record” button is tapped), you might want to hang on to this `Task` for future reference, so you can `cancel` it later. E.g.:

   ```swift
   @MainActor
   class Recorder: ObservableObject {
       @Published var recordingTimeSeconds: TimeInterval = 0
       private var timerTask: Task<Void, Error>?

       func startRecording() {
           timerTask = Task {
               for await tick in AsyncTimerSequence(interval: .seconds(1), clock: .continuous) {
                   …
               }
           }
       }

       func stopRecording() {
           timerTask?.cancel()
           timerTask = nil
       }
   }
   ```
5. Since we are talking about cancelation, you have similar concerns with the block-based solution outlined in point 1, above:

   ```swift
   @MainActor
   class Recorder: ObservableObject {
       @Published var recordingTimeSeconds: TimeInterval = 0
       private weak var timer: Timer?

       func startRecording() {
           timer?.invalidate() // in case we accidentally call this twice, make sure to invalidate prior timer so you don’t keep it running, but lose any reference to it
           timer = .scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
               guard let self else {
                   timer.invalidate()
                   return
               }

               Task { @MainActor [interval = timer.timeInterval] in
                   self.recordingTimeSeconds = interval
               }
           }
       }

       func stopRecording() {
           timer?.invalidate()
       }
   }
   ```
6. You might not want to use timers at all. E.g., depending upon how/what you are “recording”, there might be an alternative method to keep track of the progress. E.g., [AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/) has delegate methods for reporting the `CMTime` as the recording progresses. Where appropriate, you might want to see if your “recording” API offers native progress information.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. The `Task { @MainActor ...` is accurate enough for my purpose. I did some simple time calculations and the variation between runs is about +- 1 millisecond

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `Timer`'s block parameter is an `@Sendable` closure, meaning that it could possibly be executed in a different concurrency domain. Which, in turn, means that if you want to mutate your instance's property in that `@Sendable` closure, you need to account for a switch in concurrency domains.

The easiest way to solve that (in your case) is marking your class with `@MainActor`, since an `ObservableObject`'s `@Published` property will probably be used on the Main thread (by UIKit, SwiftUI, whatever).

```
@MainActor class Recorder: ObservableObject
```

Which will then mean that when your Timer closure executes, you need to switch concurrency domains in order to update the property. And since mutating from another concurrency domain must be done asynchronously, you also need to either:

- Run your closure on the main actor:

```
let timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { t in
    Task { [timeInterval = t.timeInterval] in
        await MainActor.run { self.x = timeInterval }
    }
})
```

- Create a method in the @MainActor class, and update the value via that:

```
func updateRecordingTimeSeconds(to interval: TimeInterval) {
    self.recordingTimeSeconds = interval
}

func whatever() {
    let timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { t in
        Task { [timeInterval = t.timeInterval] in
            await self.updateRecordingTimeSeconds(to: timeInterval)
        }
    })
}
```

For both of the above solutions, I do not get a compiler warning.

Of course, you could also make your class be safe to use in `@Sendable` closures by either making it conform to `Sendable` (or if you can't but you are sure you made it concurrency-safe by marking it `@unchecked Sendable`), but those seem like solutions going way beyond what you need.

Oh and a p.s.: you say

> "The timer in my case needs to update the value without any possible delays."

That is not the case in your example either, if you read the Discussion for `RunLoop.add(_:mode:)` - it clearly says that the block will be executed on **or after** the timer expires.